# How to Create a Restful Webservice in Php which return Json

Tags: php, web-services

I want to create a Restful Web service in Php which returns json format. So that Can be consumed from other mobile and Web Applications.

I wanted to Create a Get Method.

Comment: That's a great idea, but could you ask a question about a specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
// index.php
<?php 
  header('Content-type: application/json'); 
  echo '{"status":"restful"}'; 
?>
```

Put on your webserver and bam! I would argue that you now have a VERY restful web service that can be consumed from other mobile and web applications. In json format nonetheless.

Sorry, I was trying to be cheeky. But if this worked for you, then you might as well serve a `file.json` with `{ "something":"somethingelse" }` directly from your webserver. No PHP needed. At least not for GET requests.

You can even put it in the same folder as your webapp and do a `$.get('file.json')` or $http.get or axios.get or whatever get floats your boat.

Answer (score 0):

To send a json response you have to serialize the content. In order for doing it you can use [jms/serializer](https://packagist.org/packages/jms/serializer), [here](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) you can find the documentation for this library. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) is a PHP micro framework that helps you quickly write simple yet powerful web applications and RESTful APIs. If you want to go Vanilla try this tutorial: [Building a Simple Web API with Vanilla PHP](https://gist.github.com/odan/e791bb29e2a1eab4ac6f2be4bbf86e12)